# ATtiny85 won't wake from sleep

Tags: sleep, attiny85

My ATtiny 85 won't wake up!

The purpose of the device is to monitor a reed switch and give a 20 ms output pulse on every alternate positive-going transition of the reed switch input. The device should go to sleep after 30 s of inactivity. It should wake up on reed switch activity (rising or falling edge).

```
/*
          ATMEL ATTINY 85
              +-\/-+
        PB5  1|    |8  Vcc
        PB3  2|    |7  PB2 (INT0) reed switch input (1 MΩ ext. pull-up)
        PB4  3|    |6  PB1        output
        GND  4|    |5  PB0 
              +----+
*/
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <elapsedMillis.h>

const int hallPin = 2;            // Reed switch in this case.
const int magnetPin =  1;         // Output.
const long debouncing_time = 15;  // Debouncing time in milliseconds.

volatile int hallState = 0;       // variable for storing the hall counter
volatile bool hallMem = 0;        // One-shot memory.
volatile unsigned long last_micros;

elapsedMillis timer;

void setup(){
  pinMode(magnetPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(hallPin, INPUT);
  // Attach an interrupt to the ISR vector. DO I NEED THIS?
//  attachInterrupt(0, pin_ISR, RISING); //default interupt pin is always 0 on ATtiny85 (physical pin 7).
  timer = 0;                             //Reset the timer
}

void loop(){
  if(digitalRead(hallPin) && !hallMem){
    hallMem = true;               // One-shot memory.
    hallState++;
    delay(debouncing_time);       // Keep it simple.
    timer = 0;
  }
  if(!digitalRead(hallPin)){
    hallMem = false;              // Allow re-trigger.
  }
  if(hallState > 1) {
      digitalWrite(magnetPin, HIGH);        // Send 20 ms pulse to sensor activation coil.
      delay(20);
      digitalWrite(magnetPin, LOW);
      hallState = 0;                        // Reset the trigger.
  }
  if(timer >= 30000) {                      // No activity.
    system_sleep();
  }
}

// From http://interface.khm.de/index.php/lab/experiments/sleep_watchdog_battery/
void system_sleep() {
  GIMSK |= _BV(PCIE);                     // Enable Pin Change Interrupts
  PCMSK |= _BV(INT0);                     // Use INT0 (PB2) as interrupt pin
  ADCSRA &= ~_BV(ADEN);                   // ADC off
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);    // replaces above statement

  sleep_enable();                         // Sets the Sleep Enable bit in the MCUCR Register (SE BIT)
  sei();                                  // Enable interrupts
  sleep_cpu();                            // sleep

  cli();                                  // Disable interrupts
//  PCMSK &= ~_BV(INT0);                  // Turn off INT0 (PB2) as interrupt pin
  sleep_disable();                        // Clear SE bit
  ADCSRA |= _BV(ADEN);                    // ADC on

  sei();                                  // Enable interrupts  
  
  timer = 0;          // Reset the sleep timer on wake-up.
}

ISR(PCINT0_vect) {
}
```

Can anyone spot my error that is preventing a wake-up?

What is the ADC enabling instruction doing? Do I need it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Try to replace the PCMSK |= _BV(INT0);  with PCMSK |= _BV(PCINT2);

Comment: @gbg, that seems to be doing something, thanks. I'm going to add in an "awakeLED" so I can monitor the sleep status. It's bedtime in Ireland.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem lies here:

```c
PCMSK |= _BV(INT0);  // Use INT0 (PB2) as interrupt pin
```

You seem to have mixed up two sorts of interrupts:

1. INT0 (External Interrupt), which only works on pin INT0 (i.e. PB2)
   and can sense low-level, rising edge, falling edge, or any change.
2. PCINT0 (Pin Change Interrupt), which works on any IO pin, but can
   only sense “any change”.

Since you are sleeping in PWR_DOWN mode, pin change interrupt is the
appropriate choice. All your program is consistent with this choice but
for the line above.

The `INT0` macro has the value 6. It represents bit 6 of `GIMSK`, which
is used to enable the INT0 interrupt. Not what you want. Bit 6 of
`PCMSK` is reserved, so you are not supposed to touch it. If you want
the pin change interrupt to sense changes in pin PB2 (aka PCINT2), you
instead have to:

```c
PCMSK |= _BV(PCINT2);  // sense changes in PCINT2 = PB2
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. It works now. Can I leave out the `ADCSRA` lines as I'm not using any analog functions?

Comment: @Transistor: Indeed you can.